# How to use mathjs in a normal JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjs

I am trying to use the node package [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/) in a calculator app I am creating. The problem is, I am not running it with node, it is a website I am creating. How can I use mathjs features in my JavaScript on my website?

Comment: https://mathjs.org/docs/getting_started.html#browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [download the library](https://mathjs.org/download.html) and just include it in your `head` section as a `script` tag.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="..path to downloaded file" />
</head>
```

Or you can avoid downloading it and simply do:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjs" />
</head>
```

Comment: You *could* download it, never mentioned he needs to.

Comment: I've tried that but when I go to reference it in my JS it gives me `math not defined`

Comment: @TimTam make sure you perform any code after window `load` event has triggered. For instance, do: `window.onload = () => {...your code here }` right below the library import script.

Answer (score 1):

On their site, they offer it via cdn at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/7.5.1/math.min.js

You can add that link in your page and then it's available via `math` variable

```js
console.log(math.add(1, 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/7.5.1/math.min.js"></script>
```

How/When/Where you load it is heavily dependent on your site's needs.